# Multi head full-screen window by gtk (rust)

Tags: gtk

I'm new to gtk.
I want to create a window on multi monitors(heads) environment.

1. At first, create a full-screen window across two or more monitors(side by side).
2. On some event, un-full-screen the window, set size(width/height) and move it to specific position(xpos/ypos).

But even the full-screen mode does not work well by my following code(written by Rust/gtk library). It does full-screen on only one monitor (sometimes on left monitor, sometime on right monitor).

How to do it?

```
use gtk::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap();
    let app = gtk::Application::new(None, gio::ApplicationFlags::FLAGS_NONE);
    app.connect_activate(|app| {
        let win = gtk::ApplicationWindow::new(app);
        win.fullscreen();
        win.show_all();
    });
    app.run();
    // On some event,
    // win.set_size_request(2280, 1920);
    // win.move_(0, 0);  // works on both x11 and wayland?
}
```

Though written by Rust, the other language example or reference link is also good.